# How can I conditionally add elements to a jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there a way in which I can conditionally add elements into a postgres jsonb array? I'm trying to construct an array to be added into a larger object where most of the elements are always required but I'd like to have some of them optional.

As a simplified example:

```sql
select jsonb_build_array(
    jsonb_build_object('a', a),
    jsonb_build_object('b', b),
    jsonb_build_object('c', c),
    case when a + b <> c then
        jsonb_build_object('error', c - (a + b))
    end
) from ( values (2, 2, 5) ) as things (a,b,c);
```

This works fine when a+b<>c but when a+b=c i get a null in the array.e.g.

```
sophia=> \i ~/cc/dpdb/migration/foo.sql
              jsonb_build_array               
----------------------------------------------
 [{"a": 2}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 5}, {"error": 1}]
(1 row)

sophia=> \i ~/cc/dpdb/migration/foo.sql
          jsonb_build_array           
--------------------------------------
 [{"a": 2}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 4}, null]
(1 row)

sophia=>
```

Is there a way to add the element without the null or if added, remove the null? Obviously, I could put the whole block in a case and duplicate the first few lines but that would be rather ugly and verbose. There's jsonb_strip_nulls but that only works on objects not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a second step because you cannot create "no element" in your syntax. Either you really separate both cases with two different array creations or you have to conditionally adjust the created array afterwards:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=255c4e9af5995e82eb2e78c9b548c1ad)

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a + b <> c THEN
        my_array || jsonb_build_object('error', c - (a + b))
    ELSE
        my_array
    END 
FROM (
    select 
        a, b, c,
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('a', a),
            jsonb_build_object('b', b),
            jsonb_build_object('c', c)
        ) AS my_array
    from ( values (2, 2, 5), (2, 2, 4) ) as things (a,b,c)
) s
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't think of dropping the whole thing in a nested from. it's not the most elegant of solutions but it solves my problem.